# writing file from post request in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

Working with express to create a file transfer tool, and I've almost gotten everything completed. Just need to figure out how to get the data from the request written to file.

My issue appears to be stemming from not knowing where the file contents are placed in the request object.

**My code to process sending the request**

```
let file = watcher.getOneFile(config.thisLocation);
console.dir(file);
let contents = fs.readFileSync(file.fullPath, 'utf-8');
console.log(contents);
let form = {
  attachments: [
    contents
  ]
}
rq.post({
  url: `http://${homeAddress}:${port}/files/?loc=${config.thisLocation}&file=${file.fileName}`,
  headers: {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  formData: form
}, (err, res, body) => {
  // body = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(body);
});
```

and when I get the request on the server, I'm not sure where the file contents actually are.

**Code for handling the request**

```
app.post('/files', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.loc);
  // console.dir(req);
  let incoming = watcher.getOutputPath(req.query.loc, config.locations);
  console.log(incoming);
  console.dir(req.body);
  // console.log(req.body);
  // let body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  console.log(req.query);
  let filename = path.join(incoming, req.query.file);
  console.log(filename);
  fs.writeFile(filename, req.body, (err) => {
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(`Successfully wrote file: ${path.join(incoming, req.query.file)}`);
  });
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Where on the Request Object is the file contents?

Comment: have you tried `req.file` or `req.files`

Comment: when logging them, they're undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't access the file content in any straightforward way. I recommend you to use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) or similar package to parse form-data requests.

Here is how can you read file content using `busboy` and write it to the file system:

```
const Busboy = require('busboy');

app.post('/files', (req, res) => {
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mime) => {
    const newFilename = `${Date.now()}_${filename}`,
      newFile = fs.createWriteStream(newFilename);

    file.pipe(newFile);

    file.on('end', () => {
      console.log(`Finished reading ${filename}`);
    });
  });

  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Finished parsing form');

    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this,. I will try this out. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Post if you will have any problems with this.

Comment: Just tested with PostMan, and it works! now to test with my other code!

Comment: Yep got it working with some modifications for my use case! Thanks!